# OFFSET não funciona no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, servidor

Desenvolvi a paginação do lado sql em meu SQL Server 2014, quando joguei em produção deu o problema com o `OFFSET` porque o servidor tem sql 2008.

Tentei implementar de outro jeito mas não obtive sucesso.

Alguém sabe algum outro método?

Segue o código

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[BGC_SP_LEAD_SEARCH_DAL_NOVOPARTNER] (    
 @ID_LEAD NUMERIC(18) = NULL,  
 @NR_CNPJ NUMERIC(18) = NULL,  
 @DS_NOME VARCHAR(100) = NULL,  
 @ST_STATUS CHAR(1) = NULL,  
 @DS_BSPDIS VARCHAR(100) = NULL,  
 @ID_PESSOA NUMERIC(18) = NULL,  
 @ID_GERENTE VARCHAR(50) = NULL,  
 @ID_TIPOPROJETO NUMERIC = NULL,  
 @ID_AREANEGOCIOS INT = NULL,  
 @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS VARCHAR (50) = NULL,  
 @FL_NOMEADA INT = NULL,  
 @ID_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(50) = NULL ,
 @ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR INT = NULL,  
 @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
 @pageNumber int,
 @RowsPerPage int  
) AS  
BEGIN  
 /*  
  PROCEDURE BUSCA POR VALORES COMO LEAD_SEARCH porém se o status for null  
  ela irá mostrar apenas Leads com o status:  
   > 'D' - Designação de Responsável;  
   > 'A' - Em Análise; e   
   > 'L' - Liberado  
 */  
 DECLARE @ID_PESSOA_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(50) = NULL  
 , @MASTER_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(1) = NULL  
 , @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO VARCHAR(50) = NULL  

  SELECT @ID_PESSOA_USERLOGADO = U.ID_PESSOA,  
    @MASTER_USERLOGADO = U.ST_PERFIL_MASTER_BID,  
    @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO = G.ID_GRUPOACESSO  
  FROM BCS_USUARIO U  
  LEFT JOIN BCS_GRUPOUSUARIOPESSOA G ON U.ID_USUARIO = G.ID_USUARIO  
  WHERE U.ID_USUARIO = @ID_USERLOGADO  

 SELECT DISTINCT   
  LE.ID_LEAD,  
  LE.ID_TIPOPROJETO,  
  TP.DS_TIPOPROJETO,  
  LE.DT_PREVISTA,  
  LE.DT_WORKFLOW,  
  LE.DS_DESENHO,  
  LE.NR_VOLUMETRIA,  
  LE.ST_RECURSOS,  
  LE.ID_GERENTE_VERTICAL,  
  LE.ID_GERENTE_PROJETO,  
  ISNULL(LE.NR_CNPJ,PCLI.NR_CPFCNPJ) AS NR_CNPJ,  
  LE.ID_BSPDIS,  
  LE.DS_JUSTIFICATIVA,  
  LE.ST_STATUS,  
  ISNULL(CL.DS_NOME,PCLI.DS_NOME) AS DS_NOME,  
  ISNULL(CL.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL,PCLI.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL) AS DS_RAZAOSOCIAL,  
  ISNULL(CD.DS_NOME,CD.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL) AS DS_BSPDIS,  
  LE.ID_RESPONSAVEL,  
  US.DS_USUARIO,  
  LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS,  
  LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS,  

  LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR,  
  LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR, 


  CO.NR_CNPJ AS NR_CNPJ_CONTA,  
  CO.FL_NOMEADA,  
  null DS_CONFIDENCIAL_LEXMARK,  
  EST.ID_ESTADO DS_BSPDIS_ESTADO,  
  GN.DS_USUARIO GERENTE_NEGOCIOS,  
  AN.DS_NOME AREA_NEGOCIOS,
  GNL.DS_USUARIO GERENTE_NEGOCIOS_LEITOR,  
  ANL.DS_NOME AREA_NEGOCIOS_LEITOR    

 FROM BGC_LEAD LE  
 INNER JOIN BCS_USUARIO  US ON LE.ID_RESPONSAVEL = US.ID_USUARIO  
 LEFT JOIN BCS_GRUPOUSUARIOPESSOA GUP ON US.ID_USUARIO = GUP.ID_USUARIO  
 LEFT JOIN BGC_TIPOPROJETO TP ON LE.ID_TIPOPROJETO = TP.ID_TIPOPROJETO   
 INNER JOIN BCT_PESSOA  CD ON LE.ID_BSPDIS = CD.ID_PESSOA  
 LEFT JOIN BGC_TMP_CLIENTE CL ON CL.ID_CLIENTE = LE.ID_CLIENTE  
 LEFT JOIN BCT_PESSOA  PCLI ON PCLI.ID_PESSOA = LE.ID_PESSOA_CLIENTE  
 LEFT JOIN BGC_CONTA CO ON LE.NR_CNPJ = CO.NR_CNPJ   
 INNER JOIN BCT_PESSOA PE ON LE.ID_BSPDIS = PE.ID_PESSOA  
 INNER JOIN BCT_PESSOATIPO PET ON PE.ID_PESSOA = PET.ID_PESSOA  
 LEFT JOIN BGC_GRUPO GR ON PET.ST_TIPO = GR.ST_TIPO  
 LEFT JOIN BCT_GRUPOPESSOA GP ON GR.ID_GRUPO = GP.ID_GRUPO  
  AND PE.ID_PESSOA = GP.ID_PESSOA  
 LEFT JOIN BGC_GRUPO_GERENTE GG ON GR.ID_GRUPO = GG.ID_GRUPO    
 LEFT JOIN BSP_ADDRESSBOOK AB ON CD.ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER = AB.ID_CUSTOMERNUMBER    
 LEFT JOIN BCT_ESTADO EST ON AB.DS_ESTADO = EST.ID_ESTADO   
 LEFT JOIN BCS_USUARIO GN ON LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS = GN.ID_USUARIO    
 LEFT JOIN BGC_AREANEGOCIOS AN ON LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS = AN.ID_AREANEGOCIOS 

 LEFT JOIN BCS_USUARIO GNL ON LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR = GNL.ID_USUARIO    
 LEFT JOIN BGC_AREANEGOCIOS ANL ON LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR = ANL.ID_AREANEGOCIOS


 WHERE ---- @ID_LEAD ----  
  LE.ID_LEAD = ISNULL(@ID_LEAD,ID_LEAD)  
  ---- @ST_STATUS ----  
  AND (  
   ( @ST_STATUS IS NOT NULL AND LE.ST_STATUS = @ST_STATUS  )  
   OR ( @ST_STATUS IS NULL AND LE.ST_STATUS IN ('D', 'A', 'L') )  
  )  
  ---- @NR_CNPJ ----  
  AND ( CL.NR_CNPJ LIKE CAST(@NR_CNPJ AS VARCHAR(18)) + '%'
   OR PE.NR_CPFCNPJ LIKE CAST(@NR_CNPJ AS VARCHAR(18)) + '%'
   OR @NR_CNPJ IS NULL  
  )  
  ---- @DS_BSPDIS ----  
  AND  (  CD.DS_NOME LIKE '%' + @DS_BSPDIS +'%'  
   OR CD.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL LIKE '%' + @DS_BSPDIS +'%'  
   OR @DS_BSPDIS IS NULL  
  )  
  AND ID_BSPDIS = ISNULL(@ID_PESSOA,ID_BSPDIS)  
  AND ( CL.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL LIKE '%' + @DS_NOME +'%'  
   OR CL.DS_NOME LIKE '%' + @DS_NOME + '%'  
   OR PE.DS_RAZAOSOCIAL LIKE '%' + @DS_NOME +'%'  
   OR PE.DS_NOME LIKE '%' + @DS_NOME + '%'  
   OR @DS_NOME IS NULL  
  )  
  AND ( LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS = @ID_AREANEGOCIOS  
   OR @ID_AREANEGOCIOS IS NULL   
  )  
  AND ( LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS = @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS  
   OR @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS IS NULL   
  )  
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------Leitor
  AND ( LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR = @ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR  
   OR @ID_AREANEGOCIOS_LEITOR IS NULL   
  )  
  AND ( LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR = @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR  
   OR @ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR IS NULL   
  )
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  AND (CO.FL_NOMEADA = @FL_NOMEADA  
   OR ( CO.FL_NOMEADA IS NULL  
    AND  @FL_NOMEADA =2   
   )    
   OR (@FL_NOMEADA IS NULL)  
  )   
  AND ( LE.ID_TIPOPROJETO = @ID_TIPOPROJETO  
   OR @ID_TIPOPROJETO  is null  
  )  
  AND ( @ID_USERLOGADO IS NULL   
   OR GG.ID_GERENTE = @ID_USERLOGADO -- GERENTE DO GRUPO ASSIGNACAO   
   OR  LE.ID_BSPDIS = @ID_PESSOA_USERLOGADO -- É DO MESMO CLIENTE QUE CRIOU O LEAD   
   OR  LE.ID_RESPONSAVEL like '%' + @ID_USERLOGADO + '%' -- É O CRIADOR DO LEAD   
   OR  LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS = @ID_USERLOGADO -- GERENTE DE NOGOCIOS DO LEAD   
   OR  LE.ID_GERENTENEGOCIOS_LEITOR = @ID_USERLOGADO
   OR  @ID_USERLOGADO IN (SELECT ID_VERTICAL FROM BGC_AREANEGOCIOS WHERE ID_AREANEGOCIOS = LE.ID_AREANEGOCIOS) --GERENTE VERTICAL   
   OR  @ID_USERLOGADO IN (SELECT ID_GERENTE FROM BGC_TIPO_GERENTE_LEAD WHERE ID_TIPO_GERENTE LIKE 'C')   
   OR  @ID_USERLOGADO IN (  
    SELECT usr_prf.ID_USUARIO   
    FROM BCS_PERFIL prf, BCS_USUARIOPERFIL usr_prf   
    WHERE prf.ID_PERFIL = usr_prf.ID_PERFIL   
    AND prf.DS_PERFIL = 'Gerente Comercial Canal'   
    OR  prf.DS_PERFIL = 'Administrador - Gestão de Canais'  
   )   
   OR @MASTER_USERLOGADO = 'S'   
   -- faz o join do US pelo ID_RESPONSAVEL  
   -- ou seja, o grupo US.ID_GRUPOACESSO é referente ao grupo de acesso do ID_RESPONSAVEL  
   --   
   --OR US.ID_GRUPOACESSO = @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO   
   OR (GUP.ID_GRUPOACESSO = @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO )--OR @ID_GRUPO_USERLOGADO IS NULL )  
  )  
 ORDER BY    DS_BSPDIS, DS_NOME, DS_RAZAOSOCIAL, LE.DT_PREVISTA  


       OFFSET ( ( @pageNumber - 1 ) * @RowsPerPage ) ROWS
             FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;

end
```

`@PAGERNUMBER` = Número da página.

`RowsPerPage`  = Registros exibidos por página.

Comment: SQL server 2014 ou 2008? Seu título está como 2008 e no texto está 2014.

Comment: @Everson Fiz no 2014 mas o servidor é 2008

Comment: @Sorack sempre que implemento isso os resultados vem duplicados

Comment: @JuniorTorres: No livro `Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Querying` você encontra trecho que trata de paginação (_paging_). Páginas 547 a 552.

Comment: @JuniorTorres: Se o servidor de produção é versão 2008, a sugestão é que ou você instale uma instância com a mesma versão no computador de desenvolvimento ou, no SQL Server 2014 de desenvolvimento, você defina o nível de compatibilidade 100 para os bancos de dados de testes (similares aos que rodam em produção na versão 2008).